# Deserializing SQL table to object collection

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to deserialize an SQL table to a collection of objects in PHP and I'm lost as to how I can do so.

In C#, the equivalent would be:

```
public class Object
{
    public string objectProperty { get; set; }
    public string anotherProperty { get; set; }
}

public void Deserialize()
{
    List<Object> collection = new List<Object>();

    // Assuming that we have an SQL statement returning a row

    foreach (Row row in returnedSqlRow)
    {
        collection.Add(new Object
        {
            objectProperty = row["objectProperty"],
            anotherProperty = row["anotherProperty"]
        });
    }
}
```

which would give me a nice collection of `Objects` to work with.

In my PHP I have the following:

```
class Book {
    public $CN; // cataloguenumber
    public $title;
    public $author;
    public $description;
    public $price;
    public $enteredby;
}
```

with my SQL statement being:

`$books = pg_query($conn, 'SELECT cataloguenumber, title, author, description, price, enteredby FROM CSBooks');`

I can easily access each value from the row like so:

```
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($books)) {

        echo $row[0] . '<br>';
        echo $row[1] . '<br>';
        echo $row[2] . '<br>';
        echo $row[3] . '<br>';
        echo $row[4] . '<br>';
        echo $row[5] . '<br>';
    }
```

But I'm lost as to how I can create an object collection and deserialize the row to a `Book` object and store it.  Is there a PHP equivalent? I've taken a look at `pg_fetch_object()` but it doesn't quite seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to use PDO and [PDOStatement::fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) which will abstract all the pg_* functions and make your db interaction easier to manage.

It will return a stdObject instead of an array by default, but you can make it map your object.

There would be a dirty solution if you really need to use pg_* functions instead of PDO... (I am ashamed to suggest it)

```
$a = ['a'=>'bla', 'b'=>1];
$shame = (object) $a;
```

Then on your class, you just write a constructor to bind the columns to the object fields...